# IE incorrectly treats HTML <button> as submit button

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have two HTML buttons; one submits a form and one closes the container dialog. The button closing it doesn't have a `type` attribute:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button class="closeDialog">Close</button>
```

The JavaScript is as follows:

```
$(".closeDialog").live("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents(".dialog").dialog("close");
});

$("form.myClass").live("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // submits the form here . . .
});
```

All of this works well in every browser but IE.  In IE, when one clicks the "Close" button, both JavaScript events above execute, but only the `.closeDialog` event handler should.

IE seems to treat a  element as a submit button, regardless of its `type` attribute.

How can one get around this misinterpretation in IE?

Comment: Perhaps add which versions / modes of IE you've tried? (not sure if it's important though)

Comment: What version of IE? Also, maybe try <input type="button">?

Comment: Always set the type button as button, reset or submit, 'cause every browser could have different handling... setting a default on rendering.
Also, it's recommended to use an input with type="button" instead of "button", as its behavior is more predictable being inside a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the second one, try : `<button type="button">`

Comment: Apparently, "submit" is the default type <i>in IE only</i>.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type='button' />
```

This will work with IE in most cases.